# Run services without an HTTP endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We have some services there only listening on a Rabbit MQ queue, and that services don't have an HTTP endpoint. It is planned it be possible to run that kind of services in GCP Cloud Run?

We don't want to change our queue to GCP Pub/Sub. We simply just want a container to run with 1 CPU and 1 GB RAM all the time. If we start up a service right now there listening on a queue and don't receive any HTTP requests, will GCP scale the allocated resources be to almost nothing, so the service cannot do any work.

Comment: What happens to the messages if there is no listener. Are they kept into RabbitMQ?

Comment: Yes, the messages is kept in Rabbit MQ. But we need them to be consumed and executed by our service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what I already did is a Cloud Run service that get the HTTP request, run the RabbitMQ listener and stop it after 14 minutes and 50s and answer HTTP CODE 200 (I set the CLoud Run timeout to 15 minutes).

Then, I configure a Cloud Scheduler, without retry policy, to call my service every 15 minutes.

It's a workaround, but I can't propose something managed, pay as you use, and pseudo full time!

*Note: Cloud Run timeout will be soon extended to 3600s (1H)*

**EDIT**

Have a look to App Engine Flex. It's serverless, scale to 1, and reboot at least once a week to update the underlying servers. You talked about Cloud Run and I was focuses on it!!

You can run a container on it (custom runtime). The same as Cloud Run, but also, a slightly different. For example, at container startup, start to listen your RabbitMQ, and Kibana handles the API request

So, have a try on it!

Comment: That sounds pretty cool. We will try that, thank you! But still... i hope this question about constant performance will be answered by an Google Cloud Run team manager :-)

Comment: With the option for constant performance will we also be able to run Kibana and services like that in Cloud Run. Services there doing some background calculation, but also is a web service

Comment: Cloud Run metrics are integrated to Stackdriver. But yes, you can also run in background other app. Only one constraint: you can expose externally only 1 port

Comment: Ah yes. I mean Grafana - we love that tool. I read about other there have problems with that hosted in Cloud Run.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know App Engine Flex. Will you then mix this and Cloud Run? Cloud Run for HTTP services and App Engine for background services?

Comment: Yes of course, you can. And more than ever since the release of the serverless load balancer feature that allow you to define an [HTTP Load Balancer and to route the traffic to serverless backend](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts), like Cloud Run and App Engine (and Cloud Function). Like this, you have only one entry point, one IP, one domain (so, no cors issue) and you dispatch the traffic how  you want!)